# CKeditor: How to balance HTML tags on save? (they balance on load)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've been having issues where someone may paste code from elsewhere into CKeditor, leaving HTML tags open, or including closing tags that shouldn't be there.

I notice that when the view changes from Source to HTML, the tags are balanced. So this happens on load, and when Source is toggled, but not on save.

To see this in action, view Source, enter some HTML with an open tag but no matching closing tag, view the HTML version, view Source - it's fixed.

Even if it means quickly switching to Source and then to HTML, how can I trigger this tag balancing on save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if its the correct approach. When I inspect the `Source` button, its calling a function `CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(52, this);`.

And since switching to Preview mode from HTML markdown, the editor is auto closing the tags, before saving, you can switch to Preview mode to force it to close open tags.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {} );

var isSourceOn = false;

function saveMyEditor() {
  if(isSourceOn)
    CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(52, this);
}

editor.on('instanceReady', function( event ){    
  editor.on( 'mode', function( evt ){
    if(editor.mode != 'source') {
      isSourceOn = false;
    } else {
      isSourceOn = true;
    }
  });
});
```

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzOmwB?editors=1010)

**Edit:**
Can you try this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {} );
editor.commands.source.exec();
```

It is toggling the source button properly. So before saving, you can switch to live preview and then save. So it would close the tags.

Comment: What does 52 refer here? And 'this' has the scope of current window? Why do we need window's current reference here?

Comment: I inspected the source code at [ckeditor](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sourcearea.html) in devtools, and the Source button's click was binded this way. 52 is just the array index of functions it is storing. In that page, CKEDITOR was with global scope, i guess thats why they could use 'this'. Anyway the onclick function is taking only one argument, (See image -> https://ibb.co/izJZ7o ) hence I think we need not pass 'this' here.

Comment: In my code, it is having index 3. So the index depends upon the CKEditor instance or CKEditor version?

Comment: It looks like it depends on the number of instances in that page and buttons. If it's possible try contacting their support, or in GitHub, how to simiulate Source button's click.

Comment: In plain js, var link = document.querySelector('#cke_33'); link.click() would also click the queried element. So you can select the anchor tag and call the click function, again, we need to need to know the id of the source button.

Comment: Generating a unique id for source button is random as the index for call function. So they both have the same level of randomness, something which cannot be generalized.

Comment: `editor.commands` has list of all commands that can be called. Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrXxog?editors=1010

Comment: That worked the way I needed! And doesn't perform any lag too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach will be disabling the submit button when user switches to source mode. That way you will avoid flickering between modes just before sending data to server. Please see this very basic codepen to get an idea of how it may work.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {

} );

editor.on('instanceReady', function( event ){
  var submitBut = document.getElementById('my-submit'),
      submitWarn = document.getElementById('submit-warn');

  editor.on( 'mode', function( evt ){
    if( editor.mode == 'source') {
      submitBut.disabled = true;
      submitWarn.style.display = 'inline';
    } else{
      submitBut.disabled = false;
      submitWarn.style.display = 'none';
    }          
  });
})
```

[live preview on codepen](https://codepen.io/j_swiderski/pen/PazdZb)

Comment: But I don't want to disable the source mode. I need to enable the save button in both the modes. Any way to switch back to preview mode?

Comment: Sorry, I have meant disabling the submit button and not the source button. I have edited my comment. Please consider what I have written as it makes no sense to allow saving in source mode when HTML may be invalid. Flickering between modes right before save is also much worse than disabling submit button in source mode. Please at least think about it.

Comment: Disabling save button is not as per my requirement. Any HTML parser function of CKEditor for parsing the final text? I tried [this](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_htmlParser.html), but doesn't work.

Comment: No, you need to be in wysiwyg mode for those functions to work. They need a document which is not available in source mode (there is plain textarea only).